# Typescript `could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint` error

Tags: typescript, generics

I keep getting `could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint` error when I return result that should fit the expected type of a function, and I can't understand what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code, all irrelevant details removed:

```
type User = { }

interface BasePageProps {
    user: User
}

type GetServerSidePropsResult<P> =
  | { props: P }

type PropsWithUser = <TProps extends BasePageProps>(
    callback: (user: User) => Promise<Omit<TProps, 'user'>>
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<TProps>>

export const testFunc: PropsWithUser = async (callback) => {
    const user = {}
    return { props: {
            user,
            ...(await callback(user))
        } }
}
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

> '{ user: {}; } & Omit<TProps, "user">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TProps', but 'TProps' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BasePageProps'.

[Here's this example on TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATlAvFA3lAvgKDwSwDtgkAzAQwGNoAhchABXIHMIHEB7MODHASACuCRAC5YwnLhyhIUAOIRgAZSQA3JEvwATNp24AlCHAEAbYAB4GAPlQ4oUAD4YoYPXDENseGdHZc4AOr4wAAW8EioUOYAKn7cUBAAHiSEWjx0jCy6-lYAFPyU5CYmAEZUANZiuUJIYuGIAJSoNn4AtvgI5gDy7RaxbgA0UADkNYjDVlY4TSgtnO2dCspqGtrZBkamfXFwk3hJYByIwFCUHIRwJySXAGIChJQebkGh9ZH0IA9QuYXFZZTlGY2dAFc6XKBjSLoXD2eyIRQCRCEZyufxiEF8TFjAb8TEAOgJuXIAHdyMFTkVShVqsIGg1cVgvFIgA).

Why is the potential `TProps` that was instantiated with a different subtype a problem? How can I fix it?

P.S.: You may notice that these types are taken from Next.js. However, this problem has nothing to do with Next.js itself, so please don't it's tag to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function's valid signature is:

```typescript
type PropsWithUser = <TProps extends BasePageProps>(
    callback: (user: User) => Promise<Omit<TProps, 'user'>>
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<BasePageProps & Omit<TProps, 'user'>>>
```

or you can remove some repetition:

```typescript
type PropsWithUser = <TProps extends BasePageProps, TO = Omit<TProps, 'user'>(
    callback: (user: User) => Promise<TO>
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<BasePageProps & TO>>
```

A counter-example to prove the compiler is right to raise the error about your code. Let's define a concrete example of `TProps` type that extends `BasePageProps` but doesn't pass function's result typecheck:

```typescript
type User = { }

type AnotherUser = { a: string }

interface TProps {
    user: AnotherUser
}

interface BasePageProps {
    user: User
}

type Eq = TProps extends BasePageProps ? true : false // type Eq = true

type PropsWithUser = <TProps extends BasePageProps>(
    callback: (user: User) => Promise<Omit<TProps, 'user'>>
) => Promise<GetServerSidePropsResult<TProps>>
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbkR8W)

So your function should return the result with type `Promise<{ props: { user: AnotherUser, ... } }>`. That it clearly does not.

Just as the error says: `'{ user: {}; } & Omit<TProps, "user">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TProps', but 'TProps' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BasePageProps'`

```typescript
type User = { }

interface BasePageProps {
    user: User
}

type AnotherUser = { a: string }

interface ConcreteTProps {
    user: AnotherUser
}

// { user: {}; } & Omit<TProps, "user"> is assignable
// to the constraint of type TProps (i.e. BasePageProps)
const a: BasePageProps = { user: {} }

// but 'TProps' could be instantiated with a different 
// subtype of constraint 'BasePageProps' (i.e. ConcreteTProps)
// Which is a subtype of BasePageProps by cannot be 
// assigned with { user: User }
const b: ConcreteTProps = { user: {} } // error
```

Comment: I didn't realise that the type of a field could be also extended on a extended interface, thanks!